# How to change site URL in Jekyll when switching from development to production

Tags: jekyll

When I am developing my website locally (`jekyll serve --watch`), the HTML files in the _site dir have `http://localhost:4000` URL. However, when I deploy the site to firebase, they remain the same instead of switching to the relative domain URL. My domain url is http://blogprime.com.

So what I want is ... when I am developing the site locally, every link (CSS, JS, fonts, post link, pages ) have `https://localhost:4000/` ... but when I use the `jekyll serve` it should change to my domain name that is https://blogprime.com/ followed by the relative link to CSS, JS, fonts and other files.

Answer (score 2):

Update: I just noticed the date this question was posted!

You need not change links in production and development. You can conveniently set the "url" param in config.yml.

This does two things,

- when you do a `jekyll serve` and serve the site locally then `site.url` is set to `localhost:4000`
- when you do a `jekyll build` `site.url` is replaced by whatever domain name you set in the config.

Post this you can deploy the `_site` to the root of your server where your domain points to.